# Google Sheets: Hiding Rows Based on Cell Value Yes/No

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am brand new to scripting so any help would be appreciated.  I have searched and found some answers but still not finding a solution.

I have a simple spreadsheet called "Test", I have data validation for cell B3.

If the user inputs "No" from the drop-down box, I want the following 9 rows hidden.
if the user inputs "Yes" from the drop-down box, I want the following 9 rows to show.

Like I said there are some solutions that I have search but still not producing the result that I am trying to achieve.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mD7ub.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer. Show your code for example.

Comment: _Like I said there are some solutions that I have search but still not producing the result that I am trying to achieve._ **You need to show the code that you've tried**. How do we know what you've tried or not, what could be adapted or not, what mistakes (if any) you are making? Have you read [Google script hide rows based on cell text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46843299).

Answer (score 0):

## Hide and Show Rows based upon Validation Selection

You need to add the sheet name and set up the validation for B3.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.columnStart==2 && e.range.rowStart==3 && e.range.getSheet().getName()=='Sheet92') {//add your sheet name
    if(e.value=='Yes') {
      e.range.getSheet().showRows(4,9);
    }
    if(e.value=='No') {
      e.range.getSheet().hideRows(4,9);
    }
  }
}
```